# Puppeteer can't start chromium when run by phussion passenger

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, passenger, chromium, passenger-apache

I have a Node.js application which is generating dynamic PDFs using puppeteer, while executing in a normal Node context everything works fine, but when the app is executed by phussion passenger on my server chromium can't be started.

```
Error: Failed to launch the browser process!
[1024/115457.133468:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar (11)
[1024/115457.133994:ERROR:platform_thread_posix.cc(129)] pthread_create: Die Ressource ist zur Zeit nicht verfügbar (11)
[1024/115457.134022:FATAL:browser_task_executor.cc(339)] Failed to start BrowserThread:IO
#0 0x55b9518f3399 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x55b9518542a3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x55b951865c95 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#3 0x55b94fee828a content::BrowserTaskExecutor::CreateIOThread()
#4 0x55b95141e5e2 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunServiceManager()
#5 0x55b95141e3c7 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
#6 0x55b95147fad1 service_manager::Main()
#7 0x55b95141c631 content::ContentMain()
#8 0x55b95147e80d headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#9 0x55b95147e50c headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#10 0x55b94ee725a7 ChromeMain
#11 0x7f26d0087b97 __libc_start_main
#12 0x55b94ee723ea _start

Received signal 6
#0 0x55b9518f3399 base::debug::CollectStackTrace()
#1 0x55b9518542a3 base::debug::StackTrace::StackTrace()
#2 0x55b9518f2f35 base::debug::(anonymous namespace)::StackDumpSignalHandler()
#3 0x7f26d671c8a0 (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so+0x1289f)
#4 0x7f26d00a4f47 gsignal
#5 0x7f26d00a68b1 abort
#6 0x55b9518f1e95 base::debug::BreakDebugger()
#7 0x55b951866132 logging::LogMessage::~LogMessage()
#8 0x55b94fee828a content::BrowserTaskExecutor::CreateIOThread()
#9 0x55b95141e5e2 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::RunServiceManager()
#10 0x55b95141e3c7 content::ContentMainRunnerImpl::Run()
#11 0x55b95147fad1 service_manager::Main()
#12 0x55b95141c631 content::ContentMain()
#13 0x55b95147e80d headless::(anonymous namespace)::RunContentMain()
#14 0x55b95147e50c headless::HeadlessShellMain()
#15 0x55b94ee725a7 ChromeMain
#16 0x7f26d0087b97 __libc_start_main
#17 0x55b94ee723ea _start
  r8: 0000000000000000  r9: 00007ffc830b13d0 r10: 0000000000000008 r11: 0000000000000246
 r12: 00007ffc830b2698 r13: 00007ffc830b1670 r14: 00007ffc830b26a0 r15: aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa
  di: 0000000000000002  si: 00007ffc830b13d0  bp: 00007ffc830b1620  bx: 00007ffc830b1694
  dx: 0000000000000000  ax: 0000000000000000  cx: ffffffffffffffff  sp: 00007ffc830b13d0
  ip: 00007f26d00a4f47 efl: 0000000000000246 cgf: 0000000000000033 erf: 0000000000000000
 trp: 0000000000000000 msk: 0000000000000000 cr2: 0000000000000000
[end of stack trace]
Calling _exit(1). Core file will not be generated.


TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md

    at onClose (/var/www/vhosts/baumhaustechnik.de/buchungssystem/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/launcher/BrowserRunner.js:189:20)
    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/www/vhosts/baumhaustechnik.de/buchungssystem/node_modules/puppeteer/lib/launcher/BrowserRunner.js:180:76)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:205:15)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:272:12)
```

is there any way to go around this or do I have to generate the PDFs outside of the passenger instance?

Comment: Did you find any workaround? I have this same problem.